# Rank r matrix approximation via SVD in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Suppose we have computed the **svd** of a matrix A in Julia via **svd(A).** How would we compute a rank **r** approximation of that matrix A in Julia, given we already have its singular value decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something as follows:

```
using LinearAlgebra

A=rand(10,20)

svd_fact = svd(A)

function r_rank_approx(svd::SVD,r::Int)
    @assert 1 ≤ r
    
    n,m = size(svd)
    u,s,v = svd

    r = min(r,min(n,m))

    # like u[:,1:r]*Diagonal(s[1:r])*v[:,1:r]'
    # but reduce number of memory allocs
    view(u,:,1:r)*Diagonal(view(s,1:r))*view(v,:,1:r)'
end

r_rank_approx(svd_fact,2)
```

The idea is to only use the first r-singular values from the complete SVD.

**Note:** if you have big matrices, there are dedicated algorithms that compute a truncated SVD directly, see [TSVD.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/TSVD.jl) by example.